# Jquery use trigger click after $.when()

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code that response to a edit function and after that it will trigger the loademployees function and load again the table with the edited value but the problem is that when I apllied it in a $.when() it does not trigger the loademployees function. Please take a look at my code for clarity:

```
$(function(){
$('#editEmployeeForm').submit(function(e){
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/updateEmployee');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/updatePersonalData');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/updateGovernment');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/updateRequirements');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/updateContacts');?>",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
        }));
        $('#modalEditEmployees').modal('hide');
        $('#btnloadEmployees').trigger(e.type);
    });
});
```

and here is the function that to be triggered:

```
$('#btnloadEmployees').click(function(e){
var dept = $('#cmbdept').val();
if(dept == "SEWING")
{
    var section = $('#cmbsection').val();
    var line = $('#cmbline').val();
    var formData = {dSection:section,dLine:line,dept:dept};
}
else
{
    var formData = {dept:dept};
}
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo site_url('tms/loadEmployees');?>",
    data: formData,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $('#tblEmployees tbody').empty();
        $('#tblEmployees tbody').append(response);
    },
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

refer to https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/, the syntax of `$.when` should be like

```
$.when( $.ajax(".."), $.ajax(".."), $.ajax("..")).done(function(){
    $('#modalEditEmployees').modal('hide');
    $('#btnloadEmployees').trigger(e.type);
});
```

and you should put `e.preventDefault();` before when for prevent form default submit behavior.